# internal server error for htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, internal-server-error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

In server error log I found this.........

```
[Sun Sep 29 11:41:38 2013] [11364218] [core:error] [client 59.91.129.173:61139] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace
```

// My htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

if i remove my htaccess then also this problem arise

I am stucked for this issue

Please help me for this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` code so that it can be investigated.

Comment: Look into redirect and rewrite directives in .htaccess that could be causing an infinite loop.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Answer (score 3):

Your .htaccess is stuck in a re-direct loop. For instance, http forwarding to https, forwarding back to http, back to https, forever.  The site as configured cannot actually deliver a page, and the browser is complaining about it.

If you post the .htaccess for us (change sensitive info, as needed) then we can tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Comment: That won't work. Try this: 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]